# Is there a technique to make a shower mirror fog-free?

Tags: shower, mirror

We want to install a permanent mirror in a new shower, but hope to find a permanent way to prevent it from fogging up.

I have seen gooseneck mirrors that hook up to the showerhead itself so as to run hot water behind the mirror, which supposedly prevents fogging, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do a permanent installation. I'm imagining maybe building in a mirror to the wall of the shower and somehow running the hot water pipes behind it. Would that work? Have you ever seen anything like this? Or is there a better way to get a fog-free mirror experience in the shower?

Comment: if you put it in the wall you can heat it with a electric element even. just to keep it 40/50deg celcuis.

Comment: rub potato on the mirror

Answer (score 22):

Yes, install heating cable behind the mirror - it will heat the mirror and water will not condense on the mirror. Heating cable manufacturers even offer some special kits for that - like this [one from DEVI](http://www.devi.com.au/shop/item/mirror-heaters).

Comment: Is it really safe to install electrical appliances in a shower?

Comment: @Spike: Heating cables for such installations feature multiple layers of insulation and even a surrounding wire mesh that can (and should) be grounded. Add to this "differential" circuit breakers - and risk of electric shock becomes lower than risk of falling and getting a head injury that way. Electric water heaters don't make you worry, do they?

Comment: @sharpooth: No, that sounds about perfect. The picture on the Devi site had it behind a sink. I didn't know it would be rated for inside showers. Also, just about everything makes me worry. I worry. I'm a worrier.

Comment: @sharptooth - We needn't worry about electric water heaters because the drum of the water heater and the plumbing has a good path to ground.  You cannot say the same about a mirror in a shower - the human could easily be the best path to ground.  I'm not saying that the mirror heaters are dangerous, I'm just saying it's not apples-to-apples wrt electrocution risk.

Comment: @alx9r: You can't be sure about what the plumbing is made of and how exactly it is laid in the ground. It can be made of plastic and therefore ungrounded. What you claim is a common misconception that sometimes causes electrocution.

Comment: @sharptooth - Good point about plumbing not necessarily being grounded.  But are you saying that the tanks/drums of water heaters aren't grounded either?

Comment: @alx9r: They should be, but that doesn't mean they actually are. Anyway claiming it is grounded just because it's connected to plumbing is damn wrong.

Comment: @sharptooth - That's not the heart of my claim at all. Rather, my claim is that water heaters have a metal chassis in contact with water in close proximity to the electric heating element that is meant to provide a good path to ground in case of failure. And that in a normal installation where the chassis is grounded a la electrical code, that grounding is the primary means of electrocution prevention.  And that similar electrocution prevention by grounding is not possible for a heated mirror because there is no chassis to ground.

Comment: @alx9r: That's not what should be relied upon as grounding. Water might be not there, water conductivity can vary depending on salts concentration.

Comment: @Spike -- As we jokingly say in chat frequently: Everything is grounded in the shower.

Comment: A heating cable is a lot of effort if in an inaccessible place. Fog-x is a good short term fix

Answer (score 17):

I'm unaware of any permanent solutions, but there are quick fixes available in the auto and dental industry. Dentists use anti-fogging solution like [this](http://www.shavenow.com/products/Fogless-Mirror-Cleaner-and-Anti-Fog-Solution-Spray-.html?gclid=CJT_kd3ki7cCFcLc4AodaF0A6A) or [this](http://us-professional.gumbrand.com/departments/clear-dip/).

I know a guy who uses [Rain-X Interior Glass Anti-Fog](http://www.carcareproducts.com.au/product/rain_x/interior_glass_anti_fog) on his car mirrors. Would probably work inside a shower, too.

[image]

Comment: I've used Fog-X it on mirrors and sliding glass doors in my hot tub room. Works well, lasts a few months.

Answer (score 8):

For the truly DIY solution, you can clean the mirror with soapy water.  The layer of soap helps reduce the fog.  It also tends to be the nearest cleaner when you're in the shower.

Comment: Actually, dish detergent is better than bath soap; it doesn't leave a soap scum film.

Comment: Shaving cream is supposed to work too. Might be worth a shot

Comment: I've also heard spit works well.

Answer (score 6):

A good ventilation fan, to remove the steam is the first step.   Then you need a heated mirror, or try to putting a floor heating mat behind the mirror.    If the mirror is warmer then the tiles then most condensation will form on the tiles rather then mirror.

Answer (score 2):

I purchased a mirror that has a water reservoir in the back. You fill it with hot water when you start your shower and it will never fog. I've been using it for a few years and I love it.

Answer (score 2):

I've learned a little trick to this: Water vapor only condenses on colder surfaces so holding the mirror under the hot shower until it has warmed up will make it no longer fog up.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a permanent solution, but an easy solution is to get yourself a facial scrub that has glycerin in it. (A lot of them do. Get one that's a gel, not a cream.) Take a little dab of that and rub it on the mirror, and it'll stay fog-free for the duration of your shower. Bonus: Maybe it'll help encourage you to use a proper facial scrub rather than just using regular soap. :)

As someone else said above, though, spit does also work, though of course is a bit grosser.

Answer (score 1):

Low voltage plastic mats which can be installed behind mirror. No danger of electrocution.
They can also be used under any flooring.

Comment: Please see the [faq#promotion] for the rules on self-promotion on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Spray some WD-40 on the mirror, then wipe it off.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is a good idea.  I've heard of WD-40 having a reaction with the reflective substance on some mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

Just spit on your mirror and smear it all over it every time before you get out of the shower. I tried all the above a long time ago and did the spit as an experiment and it worked! When you pick up your mirror to use it just give it a rinse under the water and no fog the entire use. Promise.

Answer (score 0):

Toothpaste; not one with baking soda though. It works on diving masks too!

Comment: Please explain exactly how you use the toothpaste.

Comment: I recall hearing this somewhere else, but I agree you need to offer some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, probably way too late now... And maybe too complex, but...

Run the hot water supply through some copper pipe and snake it back and forth behind the mirror which is thermally connected to the pipe, with something. I haven't worked that out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use toothpaste or shaving cream. Wipe it on, then wipe it off. The mirror will not fog up after treatment for at least several showers. Tooth paste seems to last longer than shaving cream, but it is harder to wipe off. Also, don't use abrasive (usually white) toothpaste for this... use the gel kind.

Put the toothpaste or shaving cream on the mirror when it is dry (not humid). wipe it off with a dry cloth or towel. Don't rinse it off with water.

And one other solution is to use a hair dryer before or after fogging. If used before showering, then the mirror will be warm which will prevent condensation.